# React.js application deployment issue [Working on local but occurs on deployment]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment, react-context, vercel

I am facing an issue while deploying React app on Vercel (same happens on Netlify). The problem is the application is working well locally but, when I try to deploy it, it fails to resolve the context that I have implemented. The following image shows the error:

Import statements at App.js
The project created using Vite.
[enter image description here][1]

```
import { UserProvider } from './contexts/user/UserContext';
import { LoadingProvider } from './contexts/loading/LoadingContext';
```

ERROR on Vercel:

```
Could not resolve './contexts/user/UserContext' from src/App.jsx
error during build:
Error: Could not resolve './contexts/user/UserContext' from src/App.jsx
    at error (/vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:198:30)
    at ModuleLoader.handleResolveId (/vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:22508:24)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:22471:26
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Comment: No image. Also it would be helpful if you could edit your question to add the actual text of the error, rather than only an image.

Comment: I have just  edited the question and added error text.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `contexts/user/UserContext` shows that it's expecting to find

```
contexts/user/UserContext
```

in

```
/vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared
```

I suspect you may not have a subfolder called `contexts` at that location at build time in the build environment.

Check your use of the relative path in your imports. You will need to ensure the folder ends up in the right place at build time, and that the import path resolves correctly in the build environment.

Comment: I have included two contexts in my project. UserContext & LoadingContext. Both are in the same directory, /contexts inside /src. Surprisingly, the LoadingContext is working fine and no errors occurred when I had deployed. But, when I added the other context, i got this error.

Comment: @Mahmoud then you also need to check that UserContext is set up the same as LoadingCntext to work with React and the JavaScript modules system.  For those {} to be resolved, UserContext will need to follow the same mechanism as LoadingContext in terms of how you export the class.

Comment: Also check the casing in your path: you have "contexts/user", but should "user" have an upper-case "U" for example? Other than that I think we are in the dark without seeing the code. Edit your question to add the LoadingContext and UserContext code if possible.

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue? I ran into the same error recently

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GitHub, ensure that the file casing matches both locally and on GitHub. Here's an issue I encountered and how I resolved it:

I faced a similar issue when I renamed a file, for example, `sidebarContext.jsx`, locally and pushed it to GitHub. Later, I changed the file name to `SidebarContext.jsx` locally, but it remained unchanged on GitHub even after pushing `SidebarContext.jsx`—it still appeared as `sidebarContext.jsx`. Consequently, my code worked fine locally because I imported `SidebarContext` like this in my `App.jsx` component:

```
import SidebarProvider from "../context/SidebarContext";
```

However, when I attempted to deploy on Vercel, an error occurred, stating that it couldn't reach `SidebarContext.jsx` in `"../context/SidebarContext.jsx"` from `"src/App.jsx"`. After spending a considerable amount of time troubleshooting, I checked GitHub and discovered that sidebarContext.jsx hadn't been renamed to SidebarContext.jsx. So, I directly renamed the file on GitHub to SidebarContext.jsx, and the Vercel deployment was successful.

If this does not work for you make sure the file path is correct.